# Hypergeometric relation from Legendre functions

Tags: hypergeometric-function, legendre-polynomials

When writing the relation for the Legendre polynomials
$$
P^{-\mu}_{\nu}(z) = (-1)^{\mu} {\Gamma(\nu-\mu+1) \over \Gamma(\nu+\mu+1)} P^{\mu}_{\nu}(z)
$$
in the Gauss hypergeometric representation, we obtain
$$
F\left( -\nu, \nu+1,1+\mu,{1-z \over 2} \right) = (-1)^{\mu} {\Gamma(\nu-\mu+1) \over \Gamma(\nu+\mu+1)}  {\Gamma(1+\mu) \over \Gamma(1-\mu)} \left({1+z \over 1-z}\right)^{\mu} F\left( -\nu, \nu+1,1-\mu,{1-z \over 2} \right)\,.
$$
My question is, how could one find this relation using only the properties of hypergeometric functions? Every manipulation I try using transformations between hypergeometric functions always result in 2 terms.

EDIT: Corrected the last equation.

EDIT2: I have managed to get the following steps

\begin{align}
& \left({1+z \over 2} \right)^{-\mu} F\left[ -\nu,\nu+1;1+\mu; {1-z \over 2} \right] = \\
& = F\left[ 1+\mu+\nu,\mu-\nu;1+\mu; {1-z \over 2} \right] \\
& = \sum^{\infty}_{k=0} {\Gamma\left(1+\mu+\nu + k\right) \over \Gamma\left(1+\mu+\nu\right)}{\Gamma\left(\mu-\nu + k\right) \over \Gamma\left(\mu-\nu\right)}{\Gamma\left(1+\mu\right) \over \Gamma\left(1+\mu+k\right)} {1\over k!} \left({1-z \over 2}\right)^k \\
& = {\Gamma\left(1+\mu\right) \over \Gamma\left(1-\mu\right)} {\Gamma\left(1+\nu\right)\Gamma\left(-\nu\right) \over \Gamma\left(1+\mu+\nu\right)\Gamma\left(\mu-\nu\right)}\left({1-z \over 2}\right)^{-\mu} \times \sum^{\infty}_{k'=\mu} {\Gamma\left(1+\nu + k'\right) \over \Gamma\left(1+\nu\right)}{\Gamma\left(-\nu + k'\right) \over \Gamma\left(-\nu\right)}{\Gamma\left(1-\mu\right) \over \Gamma\left(1-\mu+k'\right)} {1\over k'!} \left({1-z \over 2}\right)^{k'} \\
& = {\Gamma\left(1+\mu\right) \over \Gamma\left(1-\mu\right)} (-1)^{\mu}{\Gamma\left(1-\mu+\nu\right) \over \Gamma\left(1+\mu+\nu\right)}\left({1-z \over 2}\right)^{-\mu} \sum^{\infty}_{k'=\mu} { (-\nu)_{k'} (\nu+1)_{k'} \over (1-\mu)_{k'} } {1\over k'!} \left({1-z \over 2}\right)^{k'}
\end{align}

where I defined $k' = k+\mu$ and used the reflection formula to simplify the $\Gamma$ functions. The very last step would be to somehow turn the summation from 0 to $\infty$ rather than $\mu$ to $\infty$, but I cannot see how this could be done.

Comment: One method is to compare the differential equations of the two hypergeometric functions and then show that a transformation leads from one to the other.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! While that is true, I would like to be able to show this algebraically, since I intend to generalize this relation for another case.

Comment: Could you post the reference for your original formulas?  I am having problems with different definitions.

Comment: I actually managed to prove this some hours ago, but thank you for your interest!